spock / groovy always return null as callable result
How to reproduce
    def 'test of java lambda' () {
        given: 
        Callable<String> working = () -> {return "working"}

        and:
        def executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)

        when:
        def result = executor.submit(working)
        Thread.sleep(1000)

        then:
        result.get() != null
    }

This test will not pass.
Return always will be null.
Question
How to use java lambda so this test will pass?

Try with executor.submit((Callable)working)

Addig (Callable) solved this. If you add this as an answer with few sentences why it's working why its not worked earlier I will accept it.

Cool, I explained what I believe is going on

Groovy is choosing the Runnable variant of the submit method
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-
Which returns a future that returns null
To force it to use the Callable variant, you can cast the argument
def result = executor.submit((Callable) working)

